# "had had to read" vs "could have had to read" vs. "would have had to read"

Tags: meaning, past-tense, modal-verbs

I am not a native speaker, so understanding a foreign language while living in an environment where people don't speak English very often is a little challenging. Recently, I came across these. I would be glad if you could help with these and explain where to use them?

1. He had had to read/swim.
2. Could have had to read/swim.
3. Would have had to read/swim.

I am quite acquainted with sentences with 2 consecutive "hads" or *have* 
 immediately followed by *had*, but what good on the Earth is this little word  "TO" doing at the end of every sentence?

Comment: 'To' is part of the infinitive of the verb. "He had to swim 100 metres to reach the boat. If the boat had not been there, he _would have_ had to swim 200 metres to reach the shore."

Comment: Thanks Dear ,                                                                                                                   and  " it was better to have felt " Does this sentence convey anything different than " It was better to feel "  .As a non-native, I am unable to find difference between the two. They both appear same to me .

Answer (score 1):

These all use the phrasal verb "have to" = "be required to".

Syntactically this behaves just like the verb "have" (the full verb, not the auxiliary), but it has a distinct meaning.

So the structures are just like

> had done
>
> could have done
>
> would have done

Comment: These all use *perfect aspect*, so the phrase "have to" becomes "had to", and the example "done" replaces "had to swim", etc.